# A reliable way to set #required on form fields that are attached to a form via field_attach_form

Tags: 7, entities

I need to be able to reliably set `#required = TRUE` on form fields that are attached via `field_attach_form`.  Some fields might be `$form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#required'] = TRUE` while others are `$form['field_name']['LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['#required'] = TRUE`.

I first went to `field_form_get_state()` - I tried to change `$state['instance']['required'] = TRUE` and then use `field_form_set_state()`, this didn't work.  I can walk the array, setting the value every time I find a #required key, but that feels like a terrible solution.

For some context: consider a scenario in which an admin can permit access to a section of the site *if* a user completes certain fields attached to the user entity.  Section A might require first_name while Section B requires phone number.  These are admin configurable - the admin can create an access control and attach the whichever form fields she chooses to this section.  None of the form fields are required upon registration.

Edit: Still looking for a better solution but I ended up setting all of the `#required = TRUE`:

```
private function makeFieldsRequiredRecursive(&$field) {
  foreach (element_children($field) as $_field) {
    if (isset($field[$_field]['#required'])) {
      $field[$_field]['#required'] = TRUE;
      if (!empty(element_children($field[$_field]))) {
        $this->makeFieldsRequiredRecursive($field[$_field]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The solution given in the question seems pretty good to me. However, just as an imagination exercise, if requiredness reliability is really what one wants, it could be put in place another approach: to set by default every target field as required (for server side validation purposes, i.e. `['#required'] = TRUE`) and to add via js default values as "N/A" when it is not the case of the requiredness being conditionally activated. At the end of the day "required" just means something needs to be stored/submitted, not necessarily this data will be semantically relevant or filled in by the user.